# Red5 Application specify custom playback directory

Tags: java, spring, red5

In red5 application I need to serve videos from custom directory.
I tried to implement CustomStreamFileNameGenerator, but it did not work, it still looks for videos in the root of the project. And also as you can see I added log after propert set, but it also did not invoked.

Here is what I tried:

```
@Slf4j
public class CustomStreamFileNameGenerator implements IStreamFilenameGenerator, InitializingBean {

    private final String streamsDirectory = "/streams/videos";
    private boolean resolvesAbsolutePath = false;

    @Override
    public String generateFilename(IScope iScope, String name, GenerationType generationType) {

        return generateFilename(iScope, name, null, generationType);
    }

    @Override
    public String generateFilename(IScope iScope, String name, String extension, GenerationType generationType) {

        String generatedFileName = streamsDirectory + name;
        if (extension != null && !extension.equals("")) {
            generatedFileName += extension;
        }
        return generatedFileName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean resolvesToAbsolutePath() {

        return resolvesAbsolutePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        log.info("properties of bean set");
    }
}
```

Then i added it in web.xml

```
<bean id="streamFilenameGenerator" class="com.red5.demo.utils.CustomStreamFileNameGenerator"
```